# Updating action properties which are objects

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, open-graph-beta

Is it possible to update an object property of a published action? I tried POSTing to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/ACTION_ID?OBJECT_PROPERTY=OBJECT_URL
  &access_token=VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

I got `true` as a response, as you do.

I can update first-level properties such as `expires_in`, just not connected objects.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot modify the object properties in this way.

You can modify action properties in this method, but if you want to update the object, you need to change the OG tags on that object's URL, and either wait 48 hrs for FB's cache to expire, or force a rescrape of the OG object properties by using the debug tool at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

or via the API by POSTing to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/id={object-id or object-url}&scrape=true
```

Comment: Thank you, but that's not what I asked. I don't want to change the object, I want to associate a NEW object to the action.

Comment: Ahh, ok, no, that's also not possible. You have to delete this action and post a new one against the correct object.